# swift-lint: appeared errors that are not in the .swiftlint.yml file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftlint

I started to work with SwiftLint in my project (version 0.41.0).
I wrote rules in .swiftlint.yml file and tried to run the project but the project is not builded due to error that not even in the .swiftlint.yml.
for example I have Line Length Violation event though I put line_length under disable_rules.
I think the SwiftLint is not reading the .swiftlint.yml file I has but I don't know why. the file is in the root folder as needed and with is builded currently.
has anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Please add your configuration file to the question.

Comment: You need to give the `swiftlint.yml` file, in case there is an error inside, but also the code you put in XCode in Build Phase to interpret it AND where is the file located too. If you go on the build logs, when it's "Run custom shell scrip 'SwiftLint Script Name", is there written  `Lading configration from ".swiftlint.yml"` before`Liting Swift files at paths`?

Comment: thanks you guys but I found the problem, a framework I wrote was missing .swiftlint.yml file for itself, kind of silly one ;)